# Percentage categorization in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I wrote code that shows the percentage of customer costs. I would like to divide buyers into categories depending on this percentage. For example, if the percentage is <50, then the client belongs to category A (I need a column in which this would be written). How can i implement this?

```
  MATCH  (c:Customer)-[b:BUY]->(p:Product)
      WITH SUM(b.count*p.unit_price) As total
      MATCH (c:Customer)-[b:BUY]->(p:Product)
    RETURN c.name AS Customer, 
           100.0 * SUM(b.count*p.unit_price) / total AS percent 
    ORDER BY percent DESC
```

[Neo4j](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ8nc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to set a new property on the Customer nodes to reflect this 'category'. How about this?

```
MATCH  (c:Customer)-[b:BUY]->(p:Product)
WITH SUM(b.count*p.unit_price) As total
MATCH (c:Customer)-[b:BUY]->(p:Product)
WITH c, 100.0 * SUM(b.count*p.unit_price) / total AS percent 
SET c.category = CASE
                   WHEN percent < 50 THEN 'A'
                   WHEN percent >= 50 AND percent < 75 THEN 'B'
                   ELSE 'C'
                 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 identical `MATCH` clauses is usually a sign that you are making unnecessary DB hits, which you should avoid if you want an efficient query.

Here is a query that just needs a single `MATCH` and also returns a `category`:

```
MATCH  (c:Customer)-[b:BUY]->(p:Product)
WITH c, SUM(b.count*p.unit_price) As cTotal
WITH COLLECT({customer:c.name, cTotal: cTotal}) AS data, SUM(cTotal) AS total
UNWIND data AS d
WITH d.customer AS customer, 100.0 * d.cTotal / total AS percent 
ORDER BY percent DESC
RETURN customer, percent, CASE WHEN percent < 50 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END AS category
```

`cTotal` is the total per customer (because in the first `WITH` clause `c` is used as the grouping key of the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `SUM`).